# An expression for the energy density inside a dielectric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, dielectric

The equation for energy density is as follows:

[image]

And A dielectric works by decreasing the Value of the Electric field by a factor of its value, lets call it k.

So I assumed that the energy density would fall by a factor of k^2

However when looking at the answers to a set of questions I was given the answer says the answer becomes:
[image]

This does not make sense to me and I fail to understand why this is so and so any help explaining this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st equation applies to the energy density in vacuum. The general expression for a dielectric is $U=\frac12 E \circ D $. The textbook result follows from $D=\kappa E$.